# how to avoid youtube is displayed in mobile player

Tags: youtube-api

I have a youtube video embebed in a simple web, but what i really want is when i click the red and white button in the middle of the youtube video, it is displayed in the youtube player not in the mobile player.

Why?
Because if i want to use the youtube api and insert some graphics or images at diferent times  during the duration of the video, that are not displayed if the mobile video player is open by default.

Could you understand what i want? Sorry for my english?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use http://www.jwplayer.com/download/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply copy the embed code from youtube ?

You can also use [jwplayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/download/) in conjunction with javascript to display whatever you want on the top of the video.

**example usage:**

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ac7KhViaVqc",
        image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Tuga. Thanks for your answer. Effectively i have used your method of insert the embebed code and it runs. When i press play in a mobile device the youtube player stay there and the video plays in the youtube player not in the mobile player. but the problem is that i am using the code showed in this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference ( youtube iframe api) and i dont know how to implement in all of this the embebed code. Could you help with that?? What i want is use the api for making interactive videos with images at different times.